# Return the value of an object created in a runSync method

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a class that extends the `MessageConsole` class which expects an instance of it's super constructur `super(String name, ImageDescriptor imgDescriptor)`. The method used to create the `ImageDescriptor` is bellow:

`ImageDescriptor.createFromImage(Activator.getImage(SharedImages.SPECIFIC_IMAGE));`

This method randomly causes `org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: Invalid thread access` because at the moment it is called, the workbench may or may not be initiated.

I read [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Why_do_I_get_an_invalid_thread_access_exception%3F) that I need to run the function in `sync` or `async` mode in order to properly perform actions on the UI, therefore I create the method bellow:

```
private static ImageDescriptor createImageDescriptor() {
    Activator.getMyService().runSync(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
           ImageDescriptor.createFromImage(Activator.getImage(SharedImages.JUSTIFICATION));
        }
    });

    return null;
}
```

`runSync` is a wrapper of the `syncExec`, which adds some checks before calling it. You can consider `syncExec` instead of `runSync`.
How could I return the value of the created `ImageDescriptor` so I can pass it to the `super` constructor?

Comment: Also I cannot call the `super()` in the `run` method because the `super` constructor must be called first in the constructor of the class that extends `MessageConsole`.

Comment: Why is the constructor of your class not called in the UI thread? Here you can see how a class that extends `MessageConsole` is used: http://git.eclipse.org/c/tcf/org.eclipse.tcf.git/tree/target_explorer/plugins/org.eclipse.tcf.te.tcf.ui.console

Comment: @howlger Oh, now I get it, you meant the constructor of the class that extends the `MessageConsole` when it's called, it should be called in an `UIThread`. Because of the implementation, the instance of the class is hold in a `static final MyClass INSTANCE` and I have the same problem, I can't acces the value from the `UIThread` later.

Comment: The `static final MyClass INSTANCE` is not a good idea if `MyClass` is used in the UIThread because it kills the lazy loading pattern and also because of UI resources.

Comment: @howlger I know that but at this moment I am only mantaining the project, therefore I can't go and reinvent the wheel unfortunately

Comment: This might cause problems when open and close multiple windows or _Console_ views. Replacing access to `static final MyClass INSTANCE` with `new MyClass(...)` might also be the solution for your problem, because the constructor is not called by loading the class (e. g. by using a static method the first time), but only when an instance of `MyClass` is really needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159458/discussion-between-john-doe-and-howlger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably other parts of `MessageConsole` have also to be run in the UI thread:

- Only **instantiate and use** a class that extends a **class design to use in the UI thread** like `MessageConsole` if and only **if it is really needed** (for instance, use lazy loading; for singletons you can use the [initialization-on-demand holder idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom)).
- If the class is required in a non-UI thread, **wrap everything**, the instantiation via `new ...` and methods calls, **that require being called in the UI thread in [`syncExec()` or `asyncExec()`](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJobs/article.html#using-syncexec-and-asyncexec)**.